# Create subdomain and set home and stats value for plesk 10.4.4 using API

Tags: php, api, subdomain, plesk

I was able to create a subdomain in my plesk panel (linux serverm and plesk 10.4.4 ) using API (with a PHP script).
But I'm not able to find a documentation online for just two things:

1. How can I set the stats property to be "awstats" instead of "Nothing"?
2. How can I set (if is it possible) the home directory for the created subdomain to be, for example `/subdomains/my-subdomain`?

Thank you very much...

Comment: Do you want change stat and httpdoc for what entery: main domain or subdomain?

Comment: For the subdomain...  I know that for setting one property I have to insert a new **property** in the packet, but I'm not able to find the correct property for setting the awstats and the subdomain folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
HTTP_AUTH_LOGIN: <login here>
HTTP_AUTH_PASSWD: <password here>
Content-Type: text/xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<packet version="1.6.3.4">
  <subdomain>
    <add>
      <parent>parent domain name here</parent>
      <name>subdomain name</name>
      <property>
        <name>ftp_password</name>
        <value>qweqwe</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>webstat</name>
        <value>awstats</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>www_root</name>
        <value>httpdoc</value>
      </property>
    </add>
  </subdomain>
</packet>
```

In case of set request will be:

```
HTTP_AUTH_LOGIN: <login here>
    HTTP_AUTH_PASSWD: <password here>
    Content-Type: text/xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <packet version="1.6.3.4">
      <subdomain>
        <set>
          <filter><id>ID</id></filter>
          <property>
            <name>webstat</name>
            <value>awstats</value>
          </property>
          <property>
            <name>www_root</name>
            <value>httpdoc</value>
          </property>
        </set>
      </subdomain>
    </packet>
```

Comment: No, sorry...it don't works. I've just only tryed to set the awstats property for a subdomain, but it fails.    Myrequest code is   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<packet version="1.6.3.4">
 <subdomain>
  <set>
   <filter>
    <id>27</id>
   </filter>
   <property>
    <name>webstat</name>
    <value>awstats</value>
   </property>
  </set>
 </subdomain>
</packet>`  and I get this error:  `error 1019 Wrong name of property webstat `

Comment: Wait...the property `www_root` works correctly, but there's no way form me to let work the property `webstat`. I always recieve the error mentioned above...

Comment: Yes, request returns error answer, but it seems to be a plesk's bug. Also I tried to set `webstat` via `site` operator and it does not work  expected.

Comment: Infact...I suppose that It could be a plesk's bug or perhaps it may be because the awstats are external modules of plesk...in any case, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I have the same problem: <code>www_root</code> is fine, when I add <code>webstat</code> the subdomain is not created: did you solve this in some way, please?

Comment: It's a plesk's bug that webstat does not work. And I do not see any workaround. Maybe it work in current stable version.